# Embeber html dentro de otra pagina html

Tags: php, html, html5

Hola estoy realizando una pagina web con PHP, pero quisiera saber como puedo embeber otra pagina HTML dentro de mi página; es decir: tengo este menú guardado en otro HTML:

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Para evitar colocarlo en todos mis archivos quisiera importarlo, pero no se como. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?, si quisiera hacerle referencia en:

```html
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
         <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <object type="text/html" data="/nav/navbar.html">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
    </body>

</html>
```

Pero no carga.....

Comment: *"Pero no carga"*. Esta última frase de hecho que **no ayuda en nada**. ¿Algún error visible en consola?

Comment: Si quieres literalmente incluir una pagina html entera, podrías usar un <iframe />. Eso es lo que quieres conseguír?

Comment: Un `object` funciona de manera similar a `iframe`. De hecho, `object` es mejor para algunas cosas (y más moderno ya que fue incluído en HTML5), permitiendo embeber no solo código HTML si no también, flash, imágenes, etc. El error de Daniel creo se debe a rutas. En valor que se le pasa al atributo `data` debe ser una ruta relativa. Ten en cuenta que, `/nav` puede estar refiriéndose como `/www/nav` en lugar de `/www/aplicacion/nav`.

Comment: Vale corrigiendo la ruta , me carga aunque sin estilos , podría ser que referencie al el estilo en el archivo que traigo?

Comment: Por supuesto, los estilos de preferencia deben ir en el layout que es, donde incluyes todos los templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando que el primer archivo se llama **header.php** y el segundo **index.php**
entonces tendrías que hacer esto, usando **require_once** para incluir el primer archivo.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: así me carga el archivo , pero solo hay un problema no me trae el css

Comment: Vale me funciono perfecto , muchísimas gracias gente

Comment: de nada daniel, @StefanNolde es un problema de php, en la primera linea lo menciona